# How to set value to auto-complete field after form submission?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a dependent auto-complete form field in my custom module. After submission the form the auto-complete field shows above the result output. Now I want that submitted value should become default value after form submission. 
I tried like this:

```
'#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['keys']) ? $form_state['values']['keys'] : '',
```

but not getting any value. I also tried like this:

```
'#default_value' => isset($_REQUEST['keys']) ? $_REQUEST['keys'] : '',
```

but still unable to get any value. someone please help.

Comment: Alhamdulillah! finally got my solution myself. I simply got a value from URL like this:

    `'#default_value' => (arg(3)!= 'none') ? arg(3) : '',`

Comment: then you should include that (without the religious notation) as an answer and accept it once you are able

Comment: yes, off course, i will add as an answer and accept it when I will able to do so. Good to see your suggestion @Geoff

Comment: It helps keep it out of the unanswered list and makes it easier for someone else looking at it in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution myself. I simply got a value from URL like this:

```
'#default_value' => (arg(3)!= 'none') ? arg(3) : '',
```